# How to get SharePoint 2010 controls in toolbox?

Tags: calendar

My application uses Visual Studio 2010 to develop an application in SharePoint 2010.

I created a visual webpart and added a `SharePoint:SPCalendarView`:

```
<SharePoint:SPCalendarView ID="EventsCalendar1" width="100%" runat="server">
</SharePoint:SPCalendarView>
```

I also found that there are many other controls which appear in IntelliSense.

How can I add these controls to the toolbox? Is there any documentation available on how to use these controls?